# Override Grails dateCreated and lastUpdated for test data only?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have several Grails 2.1 domain classes that include `dateCreated` and `lastUpdated` fields that GORM manages automatically, eg:

```
class Person {
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    String name
}
```

I *want* Grails to automatically fill in these fields at runtime, but I *also* want to create some test data where I can manually define the values of these dates. The trouble is that Grails automatically sets the values if these fields with an interceptor even when I have specifically set them.

I have seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733448/overriding-datecreated-for-testing-in-grails) which describes how to allow changes to `dateCreated`, but I need to change `lastUpdated` as well. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try using that other method?  I assume it didn't work?

Comment: @tim_yates, the method linked in the question allows me to set the `dateCreated` field manually but not the `lastUpdated` field.

Comment: Did you tested? It seems to disable all timestamps, so lastUpdated is included.

Comment: @DanVinton What error do you get?  Or is the `lastUpdated` field just set as per usual?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whoops, my mistake, the approach in the other question does work, but the entity in question was separately being saved somewhere else. It also seems that you need an explicit `flush` to make things work:

```
def withAutoTimestampSuppression(entity, closure) {
    toggleAutoTimestamp(entity, false)
    def result = closure()
    toggleAutoTimestamp(entity, true)
    result
}

def toggleAutoTimestamp(target, enabled) {
    def applicationContext = (ServletContextHolder.getServletContext()                                                           
                              .getAttribute(ApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT))

    def closureInterceptor = applicationContext.getBean("eventTriggeringInterceptor")
    def datastore = closureInterceptor.datastores.values().iterator().next()
    def interceptor = datastore.getEventTriggeringInterceptor()

    def listener = interceptor.findEventListener(target)
    listener.shouldTimestamp = enabled
    null
}

def createTestPerson() {

    def luke = new Person(name: "Luke Skywalker")
    withAutoTimestampSuppression(luke) {

        def lastWeek = new Date().minus(7)
        luke.dateCreated = lastWeek
        luke.lastUpdated = lastWeek
        luke.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is an integration test you can use an hql update statement to manually set lastUpdated.