# lastUpdated of Parent gets changed when element is added to collection hasMany how to prevent it?(Grails)

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have a domain structure like :

`Author hasMany Books`.

Both the domain has lastUpdated and dateCreated fields. This works fine but the problem is when i add new element (Book) to hasMany collection of Author. Author's lastUpdated also gets changed. So, can i prevent this for this particular case? One of the solution could be to add another field say "UpdatedDate" but that i don't want to go this route.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can probably prevent it using the method in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6852372/255227

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add method:

```
 def beforeUpdate() { }
```

To your `Author` domain and implement logic of updating `lastUpdated` field there. See related [link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html).